# bounded generic method with 'super' type

Tags: java, generics, pecs

As per a literature I read,we have juicy fruits implementign the following interface:

```
public interface Juicy<T> {
    Juice<T> squeeze();
}
```

Using bounded type variables, following method would  taks a bunch of fruits and squeeze them all:

```
<T extends Juicy<T>> List<Juice<T>> squeeze(List<T> fruits);
```

Now we need lower siblings as below to work too:

```
class Orange extends Fruit implements Juicy<Orange>;
class RedOrange extends Orange;
```

So I would expect the method to look as follows:

```
<T extends Juicy<T>> List<Juice<? super T>> squeeze(List<? extends T> fruits);
```

Instead I find the method signature to be as below:

```
<**T extends Juicy<? super T>>** List<Juice<? super T>> squeezeSuperExtends(List<? extends T> fruits);
```

What explains this difference?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `public interface Juicy<T extends Juicy<T>>`?  (to prevent `class Orange extends Fruit implements Juicy<Apple>`)

Comment: @SLaks: It's not a huge gain, as if `Apple` implemented `Juicy<Apple>` then the case you mention wouldn't be prevented.

Comment: @MarkPeters: You're right; there is no way to prevent that.  However, it would prevent `class Orange extends Fruit implements Juicy<String>`

Comment: @SLaks: There's no point in "preventing" these things. They are perfectly type safe. Why do you care?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<? super T>` within `<T extends Juicy<? super T>>` is there so that `RedOrange`, which is a subclass of `Juicy<Orange>` can be within its bound.

Imagine without the `<? super T>` first:

```
public <T extends Juicy<T>> List<Juice<T>> squeeze(List<T> fruits) {...
```

Now `T` must be a `Juicy<T>`.  The class `Orange` is a `Juicy<T>`, it's a `Juicy<Orange>`.  But the class `RedOrange` is not a `Juicy<T>`.  It's not a `Juicy<RedOrange>`; it's a `Juicy<Orange>`.  So when we attempt to call `squeeze`:

```
List<RedOrange> redOranges = new ArrayList<RedOrange>();
List<Juice<RedOrange>> juices = squeeze(redOranges);
```

we get the following compiler error:

```
Inferred type 'RedOrange' for type parameter 'T' is not within its bound; should implement 'Juicy<RedOrange>'.
```

If we place the `<? super T>`, that allows the type parameter for `Juicy` to be a superclass of `T`.  This allows `RedOrange` to be used, because it's a `Juicy<Orange>`, and `Orange` is a superclass to `RedOrange`.

```
public <T extends Juicy<? super T>> List<Juice<T>> squeeze(List<T> fruits) {...
```

Now the call to `squeeze` above compiles.

**EDIT**

But what if we want to `squeeze` a `List<Juice<Orange>>` from a `List<RedOrange>`?  It got a little tricky, but I found a solution:

We need a second type parameter to match `Orange` in the `squeeze` method:

```
public <S extends Juicy<S>, T extends Juicy<S>> List<Juice<S>> squeeze(List<T> fruits)
```

Here, `S` represents `Orange`, so that we can return `List<Juice<Orange>>`.  Now we can say

```
List<RedOrange> redOranges = new ArrayList<RedOrange>();
List<Juice<Orange>> juices = squeeze(redOranges);
```

Comment: I like this answer, but help me think through why you *should* be able to get a `List<Juice<RedOrange>>` from juicing a `List<RedOrange>`.  A `RedOrange` produces `Juice<Orange>`, not `Juice<RedOrange>` so wouldn't the `squeeze` method be unsatisfiable (i.e. impossible to safely/correctly implement)?

Comment: @MarkPeters - Interesting.  I've added a way to get a `List<Juice<Orange>>`.

Comment: My point is more that If you *can* have a declaration `List<Juice<RedOrange>> juices = squeeze(redOranges)`, then something is definitely wrong, because a `RedOrange` does not produce `Juice<RedOrange>`.  Try safely implementing squeeze. I suspect you can't.

Comment: Hmm, I read your edit as if you could still opt for a `List<Juice<RedOrange>>`.  I think your new solution correctly prevents that.  However, `T` is superfluous since it could just be a wildcard.

Comment: @MarkPeters, I originally attempted to get a `List<Juice<RedOrange>>`, but you're right, that shouldn't be the goal; a `RedOrange` can only return a `Juice<Orange>` when `squeeze` is called, not a `Juice<RedOrange>`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me the easiest way to think about this is to briefly ignore the relationship between the type of fruit and the type of fruit juice it produces.  That link is established in the class declaration; we don't need it to squeeze a bunch of `Juicy`s.

In other words, just parameterize on the type of `Juice` that the `Juicy`s will produce:

```
<T> List<Juice<T>> squeeze(List<? extends Juicy<? extends T>> fruits);
```

Here we produce a list of juices based on the common super type of produced `Juice` (i.e. the parameter of `Juicy`), not the common super type of fruit.

Then we get the following:

```
//works
List<Juice<Orange>> b = squeeze(Arrays.asList(new Orange(), new RedOrange()));

//fails as it should 
List<Juice<RedOrange>> d = squeeze(Arrays.asList(new RedOrange()));
```

Comment: +1, You have a simpler solution for generating a `List<Juice<Orange>>` than I do.